# Weird yellow background-color appears in OSX Safari

Tags: html, css, animation

I have this weird problem where a yellow background-color appears when I hover a language link when the language submenu is open. It seems to be caused by the CSS rotation that I use to animate the menu when it opens.

This is visible only on non-retina screens.

Here is an image so you can see the problem:

[image: Weird yellow background-color]

And a link to see it in action: http://cognitif.ca/mci/_integration/

I fount out that when I comment the CSS rotation that is needed for the unfold animation, it stops doing it. Removing the rotation is not an option though since I want that particular animation.

Comment: take a look to the styles that are been applied with the element inspector

Comment: This yellow background-color isn't applied via CSS. It seems like a graphic glitch made by the navigator itself. It does not do that on a retina screen, same browser, same system.

Comment: code sample for reproduce?

Comment: You can click the link I provided to reproduce the glitch. You have to use Safari with a screen that isn't a retina one.

Comment: Beautiful site theme though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I got it to stop doing that by adding a CSS rotation of 0 degree to my links. That's a weird fix, but it is one that works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `background-color: transparent;` that applied to all your  elements. Safari doesn't display it correctly, try using a specific color in HEX format and the yellow color will disappear.

Comment: I removed the line that applies the `background-color:transparent;` on all `a` tags and it still does it.

Comment: try to play around with the transparent colors to define the certain element that affects your list. I had the same issue couple weeks ago and the problem was solved by using HEX color instead of rgba.

Comment: I will do, thank you very much for your answer, if it works, I will flag it as the accepted answer.

Comment: check how's the background-color generated for this element: `#header .btn-toggle-lan-wrapper .unfold-overflow ul a`

If you're using a compiler, then try using another color in there.

Comment: When I set the background-color to black or white, it stops making the flashing yellow background. As soon as I use another color (any other) it starts doing it again. I'm starting to hate Safari a lot right now.

Comment: I found out that when I comment the CSS rotation, it stops doing it. But I need that rotation for my animation. At least now I know what causes it.